# what is the difference between the system development life cycle and the project life cycle?

Tags: java, c++, dsdm-atern

i know DSDM consists of different phases, and phase two is the project life cycle, but what is the difference?

Comment: I think this would be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life-cycle):

```
According to Taylor (2004) "the project life cycle encompasses all the 
activities of the project, while the systems development life cycle focuses 
on realizing the product requirements".
```

Answer (score 1):

The SDLC becomes a part of the PLC.

1.)The PLC focuses on the project management phases, processes, tools and techniques for effectively managing the project.

2.)The SDLC focuses on the software engineering phases, processes, tools and techniques for building and/or implementing the IT solution.

Answer (score 0):

The term **project lifecycle** models how a project is planned, controlled, and monitored from its inception to its completion.

while the **systems development life cycle** (SDLC), or software development life cycle in systems engineering, information systems and software engineering, is a **process of creating or altering information systems, and the models and methodologies that people use to **develop these systems.**

Answer (score -1):

**Project Life Cycle** is pertaining to specific project scope (customer, time, etc..). Typical phases where of Project Life Cycle may be Project Scope Definition, Implementation, User Training, Support etc.

*PLC* phases are as follows:

1. Idea generation and screening
2. Research
3. Development
4. Testing
5. Analysis
6. Introduction

In **SDLC**, software scope is pertaining to specific Product Development. Typical phases in this scenario is requirement elicitation (product features/functionalities), product development, Testing, Product Commercialization, Product support/maintenance.

*SDLC* phases are as follows:

1. Requirements gathering or analyzing user requirements
2. Designing the program
3. Coding the program
4. Documentation and testing of the system
5. Operation and maintenance of the system